# How do I create a view that displays the author information of the current node being viewed?

Tags: views

I need to show a view in the sidebar that shows information about the current node's author (Username, picture, email). How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a view with selecting a type as user.
2. Add "User:Content authored" relationship.
3. IN Contextual filters add nid and select the option of "provide
   default value" and select content Id from URL.

.

That's it :)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks that worked. I was going the other way. View as type "content" rather than "user" (same relationship and contextual filter) and it wasn't working. In theory it should work the other way as well, no?

Comment: Just tried with other way like view as type "content" and follow the same step and its working. In display i have added the username.

Comment: interesting. I must be getting tired. Thanks for following up.